# Round robin tournament where few "bad" matches are played thanks to Elo

Tags: algorithm, tournament

I would like to make a round robin tournament, but with a twist.

There are tons of round robin implementations around, but every single one I have seen so far generate a schedule and everyone follows it. My main issue I have with this is that often, toward the end of the tournament, player A faces player B, but player A knows that whatever the result, his final rank is fixed, while player B's ranking depends on his match with player A. In other words, a player doesn't care about the results, the other do. This leaves the annoying possibility that A doesn't give his/her best and thus B could get a higher final score than he/she would have if the scheduling was different (for example if A vs B was the 1st game of the tournament). This is my definition of a "bad" match

I was wondering if there was a way to compute at each step of the round robin tournament the next set of games to be played so that this issue can be avoided as long as possible. I suspect it's not always possible (10 person tournament, 9 very skilled participants, one very unskilled. After being 0-8 while everyone else if 5-3 or 4-4, the last match is a "bad" match)

---

I allow one piece of extra information : Elo ranking. Intuitively, if there are two players who are much much worse than the rest of the competition, they can expect to be beaten by everyone else, and thus only their head to head match matters. So the only way to avoid "bad" matches is to put their head to head match last.

My metric is the following : come up with a round robin scheduler that takes N players with their respective Elo and outputs a schedule at each step such that **this scheduler maximizes the average time of the appearance of the first "bad" match** (i.e : as late as possible in the tournament). The easier version is to output the schedule once at the beginning.

You can suppose that player results can be accurately represented by their Elo rating and that this rating is fixed and known.

This also changes the definition of "bad" match from : "I know for sure that this match and any subsequent match cannot alter my final ranking" to "I know with 99% probability that this match and any subsequent match cannot alter my final ranking". Of course 99% can be changed

I mean, the result is probably be along the lines of sorting all players by their Elo from E_1 to E_n and have the very last match be (E_1 vs E_2) .... (E_n-1 vs E_n). But I would like some insights

Edit :

To clarify, "You can suppose that player results can be accurately represented by their Elo rating" means that if the ratings are R_A and R_B then the winrate of A is exactly the one given by the Elo formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system)

Your standing in the tournament is simply determined by your number of wins

Comment: Is this a programming question or a mathematics question? Can you create the desired last match order and then shift the match pairs by one to get the start order? For example, (E_1 vs E_4), (E_3 vs E_6), ..., (E_n-1 vs E_2).

Comment: It is a practical question? I have a tournament to run in a year or so. I am not sure what you mean in your second sentence, could you expand on that? Edit : Well, I guess that I need to program it at some point, yes

Comment: Some sort of strategy that players with biggest difference in skill (ELO) meet first. And the closer you in skill the later you meet, in the tournament. So a the strategy would be to let the average difference in ELO, go down every round. This could minimiz the bad matches.

Comment: I would reformulate your problem. You want to pick matches so that both teams have position at stake. In case of Elo it would be the possible gain or loss of Elo, would mean change in position? Is that right? Then does your simple version take per-game changes into account or ignores them? The problem is, that if you have very weak player then it is guaranteed to have a bad match involving him if you don't update the ratings.

Comment: @GijsDenHollander It's not that simple if the standings are based on the Elo score as well. Elo is already designed in a way to counter that. I.e. players with a big difference have a big chance to either enlarge this difference by a small amount, or small chance to close the gap by large amount, but the amount is proportional to the expected outcome, so it's hard to set fixture to average out he elo ratings.

Comment: It ignores the elo changes it assumes that, player the larger ELO wins. If you wanne take into account that the Elo changes every round. Recaluate the ELO every round of a player, and keep trying place them against players, so that the difference in ELO is the largest.

Comment: Ok, but then the end standings are fixed... The official ranking must be decoupled from the Elo model, to make a difference. What points are at stake if not elo?

Comment: Actually in the Elo scoring each mach is important, in a sense that an upset has higher meaning that the expected outcome, and it scales with the chances. Maybe if you decouple scoring/ranking from the prediction model (i.e. Elo score) then you will have differences. I.e. in a football match, it doesn't make a difference whether last team beat 1st team. The stake is the same, or you have to mid-players. Using elo for official ranking it isn't. It's basically like avioiding your "bad" match by altering the stakes so it's always meaningful.

Comment: Ok, i think that if you would make a schedule beforehand. Then use the idea that the average ELO-difference should go down, every round. If you want to take into account that the ELO and ranking changes. I think that maximizing the rank difference  and ElO difference, in choosing who should play who. This would maximize the chance of players which would score similar meet as late as possible.

Comment: To be clear, the Elo is assumed fixed and known for the duration of the tournament (obtained through hundreds/thousands of plays). So no variation of Elo in between rounds. The goal of the players is to have a high ranking because of the prizes, not because it would increase/decrease their Elo. The standings are purely based on your result (no account of the Elo) like your total number of wins.